# The name 'form' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to steal some lines from a similar application.  The lines are:

```
 WelcomeScreen screen = form as WelcomeScreen;
 if ((screen != null) && (screen.Text == "Channel Bar"))
 {
     screen.Visible = true;
     screen.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     screen.BringToFront();
     return;
 }
```

After I enter this, I get the message:

> The name 'form' does not exist in the current context

I have:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Isn't form a standard object in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create a instance of a class that way, you should do it like this:

```
WelcomeScreen screen = new WelcomeScreen();
```

Comment: This code is incorrect.  `()` is required for a constructor call in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is expecting a variable named `form`. `form as WelcomeScreen` is trying to cast an object, `form`, to `WelcomeScreen`. I don't see a declaration for `form` anywhere, hence your error.

If you're inside a form class, you want to use `this`, not `form`.

If you're just trying to create an instance of `WelcomeScreen`, you can simply do:

`var screen = new WelcomeScreen();`.

Comment: I am not in the WelcomeScreen form class.  I am inside Form1 (my main form) and I want to show the WelcomeScreen class.

Comment: Yes, so if you are casting within Form1, you should cast using `this`, not `form`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming WelcomeScreen is a defined class:

```
WelcomeScreen screen = New WelcomeScreen();
```

I left out the parentheses.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. You're just showing him how to instantiate the object, not why his code isn't working.

Comment: Yes, WelcomeScreen is a class!

Comment: @Yatrix, that IS why his code isn't working.  Look at the instantiation.

Comment: What do I need to do?

Comment: Instantiate your screen object like I showed you.  Form is a base class, all forms that you add to your project are derived from it.  If all you want is a generic form then it would be Form newform = New Form().

Comment: `New` is not a C# keyword; `new` is.